# Deleting child entities in Entity Framework w/ Repository Pattern

Tags: entity-framework-5

I have a child entity:

```
public class PhoneNumber : KeyedEntityBase
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; } 
}
```

that exists in multiple parents:

```
public class Customer : KeyedEntityBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; } 
}

public class Vendor : KeyedEntityBase
{
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
    public PhoneNumber PhoneNumber { get; set; } 
}
```

When I want to delete a `PhoneNumber` from one of the parents I just null it out. Is there a way I can make Entity Framework handle deleting orphan `PhoneNumber` instances when using a Repository pattern? I believe NHibernate's `all-delete-orphan` cascade mode does this. Now to do this I have to create a PhoneNumberRepository and explicitly delete the `PhoneNumber` after I null it out on the parent, and this smells.